# Posting tweets using API secrets for own app eg "via <myApp>"

Tags: iphone, twitter

I originally used this tutorial  - http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/ to put twitter into my app. It works great, however, the tweets say 'via API' - I don't want this. I'd like it to say 'via myApp' - (I have registered my app with Twitter and have the secrets etc.

If you've done this, or know of anything that could help, please let me know.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your tweets saying 'via myApp', you need your app to authenticate with Twitter using OAuth or xAuth, which the tutorial you've been using does not cover.

OAuth/xAuth are being required for all Twitter apps by the end of next month, so you'll need to find a more updated tutorial.